# Prevent UITableViewCells from highlighting when panning

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am using a UIViewController which contains a ContainerView. Inside the ContainerView I have a UITableViewController. I have a PanGestureRecognizer in my UIViewController which I use for dismissing it. Now the problem I have is that when I pan to close the UIViewController, the TableViewCells inside UITableViewController that are touched become briefly highlighted.

I have disabled scrolling in my tableview as I don't need it.

I added this to my pan gesture handler's `.began` but it didn't have any effect:

```
myTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

I also tried:

```
myGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = true
```

but the touches are still passed to the TableView and cause the cells to become highlighted. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried to disable cell user interaction?

Comment: is your cell tappable?

Answer (score 0):

You could try immediately deselecting rows that are selected in the delegate method for `didSelectRow`.

```
extension MyViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Will prevent cells from being highlighted when selected. From my experience, this is somewhat common practice.

**EDIT:** My mistake, misread the question. In which case, you could consider using the tableView's scrollView delegate to determine when you're scrolling, and disable interaction *on the individual cells* like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var areCellsDisabled = false {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // Rest of your view controller logic here...

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {


    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        areCellsDisabled = true
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        areCellsDisabled = false
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Configure/dequeue the cell, etc.
        if areCellsDisabled {
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        } else {
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        return cell
    }

}
```

This might be taking a hammer to the problem, though. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I am already using this method. It only prevents cells from being permanently highlighted. It doesn't help with what I am asking about.

Comment: Added an alternative for you try above. Not sure if it would do what you need, but it's something to try! **Edit:** My bad, looks like you solved this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```
myGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = true
```

It may not be useful in every situation, but for my TableView it prevents the highlights from happening.